# mysqli_real_escape_string not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I just learned I had magic_quotes_gpc on (much to my chagrin). I turned that off.

My database connection is made prior to this query. I have the following:

```
$subject = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["subject"]);
$body = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["body"]);
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["id"]);


mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE press SET press_title = '$subject', press_release = '$body' WHERE press_id = '$id'") or die( mysqli_error($link) );
```

With magic quotes on, this works fine. Once I turn it off, single quotes jam up the works (with a MySQL syntax error at the quote). I thought I understood the concept but I must be missing something. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Error spit out by MySQL:
    you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's what she said' at line 1

**UPDATE #2**
Here's the echo'd query:

```
UPDATE press SET press_title = \'That\'s what she said\', press_release = \'That\'s what she said again!\' WHERE press_id = \'513\'
```

Comment: What's the syntax error?

Comment: Also show the final SQL query string.

Comment: @ThorpeObazee I've updated my original post.

Comment: Can you echo the query?

Comment: Why don't you use parametrized queries instead of escaping?

Comment: You must be doing something different from what you posted. `mysqli_real_escape_string` will escape single quotes. But your echoed query shows that there are no escapes before those characters.

Comment: Read about `mysqli_prepare()` and `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()` at php.net.

Comment: @Barmar you're right. I had one too many echo statements going and I copied the wrong thing. I am getting the escaped value (as you'll see above) but still the same error. I'll look into prepared statements, but this is perking my curiosity now.

Comment: Now you have too many escapes. There shouldn't be backslashes after `=`.

Comment: I don't see anything in your posted code that would cause the quotes around the variables to be escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a parametrized query:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "UPDATE press SET press_title = ?, press_release = ? WHERE press_id = ?") or die (mysqli_error($link)); 
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssi", $_POST['subject'], $_POST['body'], $_POST['id']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

[`Manual`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: It specifies that the types of the parameters are string, string, and integer. Isn't that clear from the documentation?